# jQuery trying to check position of an object and eventually animate it .position() .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello here is the deal:

HTML

```
<body onload="load()">
<div id="main">
    <article id="grid_wrapper">
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </article>
    <article id="move_wrapper">
        <div class="move"><span class="location"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="move"><span class="location"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="move"><span class="location"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="move"><span class="location"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="move"><span class="location"></span>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

`

JavaScript

```
function load() {

    $("#main > *.move").each(function () {

        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37) {

                if (this.position().left > 0) {

                    $(this).animate({
                        left: "-=100px",
                    }, 200);

                } else {
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                if (this.position().top > 0) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        top: "-=100px",
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                if (this.position().left < 300) {

                    $(this).animate({
                        left: "+=100px",
                    }, 200);

                } else {
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                if (this.position().top < 300) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        top: "+=100px",
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    this.stop();
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });
    });
}
var loader = setInterval(load(), 5);
```

Here is a JSFiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bDb7z/

The basic idea is to make all of the red circles move relative to its position when the right key is pressed.

The current code in the JSFiddle doesnt work for some reason. Any ideas?

P.S. I know that they will probably overlap

Solved by Noble http://jsfiddle.net/YFUD5/3/ :)

Comment: What is the actual question? where is the problem?

Comment: I expect `this.position()` to fail because `this` doesn't have a `position` property. If that's the error you are getting, the rest of your code is completely irrelevant.

Comment: ill try to do something

Comment: um..... why are you executing (well, trying to anyway, your syntax for passing a function reference is wrong) load every 5ms?

Comment: hmm ill try to edit this lets see what happens

Comment: The each you are doing on .move is also not needed, since your keydown is on document. So much wrong with this code.

Comment: any suggestions about a way to find the locating of all .move elements and ?

Comment: loop over each one inside of the keydown event.

Comment: ok this doesnt work neither http://jsfiddle.net/YFUD5/ :(

Comment: If `load()` is supposed to be called when the window loads, then you don't need it because you're already putting your JS code in `window.onload`. Check your wrap to the side.

Comment: You have a `SyntaxError` in that last fiddle.

Comment: i found it fixing now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YFUD5/2/

Comment: The `>` selector only works when the child element is _directly_ below the parent element. First off, omit the `>` selector.

Comment: Are the methods you're calling jQuery methods? If so, do `var thisElem = $(this);` and use `thisElem`.

Comment: Also, you never define `topCheck()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're just setting the event `$(document).keydown()` and not actually doing anything at the moment, so you don't need `load()` at all. In fact, you can put your script right in the `<head>` tag without any wrap. Also, `setTimeout()` seems useless and completely unnecessary. When you do use `setTimeout()`, though, *don't*  call the function you're passing in. Just type in `setTimeout(load, 10)`.

The fundamental problem here, though, is that you're using the `this` object in the functions passed into `.each()` as a jQuery object. That `this` object is just a regular element and if you want to use it as a jQuery object, you're going to have to use `$(this)`.

Here's the fiddle (sorry I said `$(document).ready()`, that's a typo): http://jsfiddle.net/YFUD5/3/

//I omitted load because your putting your JS code $(document).keydown() and I omitted setTimeout() because it made no sense.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $("#main *.move").each(function() {
            var thisElem = $(this);
            ... (Use thisElem in place of just this)
        });
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        $("#main *.move").each(function() {
            var thisElem = $(this);
            ... (Use thisElem in place of just this)
        });
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $("#main *.move").each(function() {
            var thisElem = $(this);
            ... (Use thisElem in place of just this)
        });
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $("#main *.move").each(function() {
            var thisElem = $(this);
            ... (Use thisElem in place of just this)
        });
    }
});
```